# HTML Mail Outlook - Tables and Images Broken

Tags: html, email, outlook

I'm working in a media company that sells social media management and digital magazine magazine etc. My job is to prepare a HTML Mail Template for mail advertisement. I worked with HTML but never made a HTML mail. I found couple points to make my mail template more optimized for mail clients. My problem is, When I sent my html mail to a outlook (I guess 2013 outlook), the reciever can' t show the mail properly. Tables and images look different than I created. My second problem is, is there way to prevent that  outlook or other mail clients not to block images ? Here's my html code. If you help me I would be very appreciated.
Here's my html code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>HTML Mail Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
     <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
 <tr>
    <tr>
  <td bgcolor="#ee4c50" style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td bgcolor="white" align="center" bgcolor="#70bbd9" style="padding: 40px 0 30px 0;"> 
   <a href="http://www.google.com.tr"><img src="http://financesonline.com/uploads/2014/06/erp2.png" alt="Enterprise Resource Planning" width="400" height="230" style="display: block;" />
    </a>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 40px 30px 40px 30px;">
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
   <td>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="justify" style="padding: 20px 0 30px 0;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sit amet varius lorem, at porta arcu. Nullam vitae sollicitudin est. Curabitur nisl lorem, feugiat vel tortor eget, sollicitudin varius purus. Proin lacinia orci justo, sed eleifend enim vehicula blandit. Donec arcu est, varius vel aliquet quis, sodales sed ipsum. Nulla varius fermentum ligula sed rutrum. Cras eget tellus condimentum, efficitur massa sed, eleifend ex. Mauris congue fringilla enim aliquam luctus. Praesent at placerat ante.
   </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td width="260" valign="top">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <img src="http://www.erpsafety.com/assets/img/ERP-Logo%20(2).png" alt="" width="100%" height="140" style="display: block;" />
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="padding: 25px 0 0 0;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempus adipiscing felis, sit amet blandit ipsum volutpat sed. Morbi porttitor, eget accumsan dictum, nisi libero ultricies ipsum, in posuere mauris neque at erat.
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
  <td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;" width="20">
   &nbsp;
  </td>
  <td width="260" valign="top">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <img src="https://www.arckcloud.com/images/erp-logo2.png" alt="" width="100%" height="140" style="display: block;" />
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="padding: 25px 0 0 0;">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tempus adipiscing felis, sit amet blandit ipsum volutpat sed. Morbi porttitor, eget accumsan dictum, nisi libero ultricies ipsum, in posuere mauris neque at erat.
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td bgcolor="#ee4c50" style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td>
   Column 1
  </td>
  <td>
   Column 2
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to [Outlook scaling the content to a larger size](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/151-mystery-solved-dpi-scaling-in-outlook-2007-2013), forcing your images and other declared items to resize. This can destroy your layout and there is really nothing you can do to change it - it is a setting client-side on the subscribers computer.

Your best way to fix this is to use [MSO conditionals](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/) to wrap into a single table and separate each column into a separate td. Or to use the [TD or TH stack](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/4321/order-stacked-columns-responsive-email) ([TD no longer works in Android](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how_android_is_strangling_responsive_design)) with media queries. Outlook will stretch the table to fit two columns, but will not stretch the table to fit two tables, it will instead force the second table below the first.

For security reasons, there is really no way to get around image blocking from email clients - same as there is no way to include Client-side JavaScript. Sometimes you can use [embedded images](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3927/embedded-images-in-html-email), but this comes with many pitfalls and shaky compatability. It also does not really solve the issue as most of the clients that accept embedded images already do not block images by default, making it redundant.